# Setting up test fixtures in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, fixture

We're using JMeter to ensure that our APIs return consistent results through refactorings.  To use this I need to set up some fixtures in the database before the suite is run.

What is a good configuration for doing this data set-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it is within setup /tearDown thread groups:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group

Ensure you check "Run tearDown Thread Groups after shutdown of main threads" :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan